# ODI 12c - No object could be dropped on the diagram possibly because the chosen technologies in the "Create As" dialog were incorrect

Tags: oracle, mapping, oracle-data-integrator

I am going to use reusable mapping in odi 12c, but there is a problem. When ever I drag and drop a table into the environment, it gives me this error:

> No object could be dropped on the diagram possibly because the chosen technologies in the "Create As" dialog were incorrect. Please, try again choosing a different technology.

I got confused and I do not know what is wrong because before that I was doing the same thing but suddenly this error pops out.
I was going to develop simple reusable mapping to save that for using in my other mapping.

Comment: Hi Sara, Did you find any solution for this, or why this error showed up ?

Answer (score 1):

Closing the ODI and launching again should help as a workaround for this error.

Use the command:

```
odi -clean -initialize
```

This will clear the cache and launch ODI and it should negate the error until next time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. I couldn't drag and drop any of my tables - regardless of their source.

I did not find any solution except to delete my old mapping and create a new one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30295266)